# Get tweet search into excel with new API v1.1

Tags: json, excel, vba, twitter, twitter-oauth

how i used to get tweet search into excel was simply import the data from an xml url that uses rss. However, twitter is removing the support for rss and hence I am stumped with how to get twitter feeds into excel that is able to update when i hit refresh. The issue here is that I have little programming knowledge and hence i am having trouble with this new Authentication code and I would like to know how to use VBA to retrieve the data in json format (they dont support xml too) and translate to excel.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a 'barebones' function showing the general idea; it pulls the most recent 5 tweets from a specific user's timeline (in this case, Stephen Colbert!), and outputs the tweet creation date and tweet text to rows on a spreadsheet.

```
Function get_timeline(strHeader as String) As Boolean
'strHeader is a properly-constructed header as required by Twitter

Dim objRest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Set objRest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

objRest.Open "GET", "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=5&exclude_replies=true&screen_name=StephenAtHome", False
objRest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objRest.setRequestHeader "Authorization", strHeader
objRest.send

objRest.waitForResponse

If objRest.Status = "200" Then

'We use the JSON parser from http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html

    Dim objResp As Object
    Set objResp = JSON.parse(objRest.responseText)

    Dim intZ As Integer

    For intZ = 1 To intCount

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & intZ).Value = objResp.Item(intZ).Item("created_at")
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & intZ).Value = objResp.Item(intZ).Item("text")

    Next intZ

    get_timeline = True

Else

    get_timeline = False

End If

Set objResp = Nothing
Set objRest = Nothing

End Function
```

If the above isn't sufficient to get you going, I recently posted writeups [here](http://greglib.org/tweeting-with-vba/) and [here](http://greglib.org/twitter-timelines-with-vba/) which go through the tweeting-with-VBA process in some detail, and include a number of functions/techniques that are useful for handling the OAuth authentication, URL encoding, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I described this in a blog post once.  The details are here: [JSON APIs in Excel](http://markm.cd/2012/08/json-apis-in-excel/).

Basically I used [this JSON VBA library](https://code.google.com/p/vba-json/) to run this code:

```
Dim DistCache As New Scripting.Dictionary

Function CalculateDistance(startAddress As String, endAddress As String)
  Dim key As String
  key = startAddress & "|" & endAddress

  If DistCache.Exists(key) Then
    v = DistCache(key)
  Else
    Dim request As New SyncWebRequest
    request.AjaxGet ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & startAddress & "&destination=" & endAddress & "&sensor=false")
    Dim json As String
    json = request.Response

    Dim parser As New JSONLib
    Set result = parser.parse(json)
    Set routes = result("routes")
    Set route = routes(1)
    Set legs = route("legs")
    Set leg = legs(1)
    Set dist = leg("distance")
    v = dist("value")
    DistCache(key) = v
  End If

  CalculateDistance = v
End Function
```

The cache is pretty bad, but will mean you don't run the same web query twice.  I hope you can adapt this to your Twitter question.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing JSON into Excel is described here, [source](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/json/excel-json-conversion). GL!

Comment: Thanks for the info for Json, however does anyone know how to solve the importing of data to excel?